# VBA code deleting incorrect rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that deletes a row if it has empty cells in columns D to L.
For some reason it is also deleting my title cell which is located at C8.
Anyone knows why? And how to fix it?

```
Sub RemoveEmptyRows()

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Sheets
ws.Activate

  Dim n As Long
    Dim nlast As Long
    Dim rw As Range
    Set rw = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
    nlast = rw.count
    For n = nlast To 1 Step -1
        If (rw.Cells(n, 4).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 5).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 6).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 7).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 8).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 9).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 10).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 11).Value = "") Then
            rw.Rows(n).Delete
        End If
    Next n
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: If there are blank rows at the top, `UsedRange`'s row index won't necessarily match the worksheet's row index.

Comment: Well, the code is a bit messy. E.g. defining variables inside a loop gives me nausea. But actually it is deleting every full row where there is nothing from column 4 (D) to column 11 (K). So if your cells in D8:K8 are empty, row 8 will be deleted. Try stepping through your code with F8.

Comment: or try to put something (i.e. some blank characters) in the cell "D8". Or, in the code, check for (`If n <> 8`)

Comment: Instead of all those `If x = ""` couldn't you do `If isEmpty(Range(Cells(n,4),Cells(n,11))`?

Comment: I thought the comment by @Comintern would probably be the reason, but you are always using rows as an offset from the start of the `UsedRange` anyway - it is actually the **columns** that you aren't offsetting from the start of `UsedRange`.  I would bet that you have a completely empty column in either column A, B or C, and therefore `rw.Cells(n, 4)` is not referring to column D (etc)

Comment: @YowE3K Yes columns A, B and C are empty. The reason for that i don't know, they give me the file like that and every excel file they send formatted in that way.

Comment: If your `UsedRange` starts at column D, `rw.Cells(n, 4).Value` will be looking in column G, i.e. four columns from the left of the range.

Comment: Do you just need to update you For loop to `For n= nlast to 2 step -1` because the header is being counted in the `UsedRange`?

Comment: What is an example of your `UsedRange`?

Comment: You can get around the column offset issue by just using `Set rw = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireRow.Rows`, but Wyatt's solution is probably easier.

Comment: I don't completely understand why usedrange is an issue here, If I set my columns from D to K then the range should be narrowed down to those columns.

Comment: If `UsedRange` doesn't start until column D, then `rw.Cells(n, 4)` *isn't* in column D, it's in column G. Similar with rows.  `.Cells(1, 1)` is to top left cell, wherever it happens to be.

Comment: If `UsedRange` is `$D$7:$L$34` then `rw.Cells(n, 4)` is referring to the spreadsheet row 7+(n-1), and the spreadsheet column 4+(4-1).  What is happening with rows is exactly what you need to happen, but what is happening with columns is not what you are expecting.

Comment: It starts at column G because of the loop?? or because of rw.cell(x,x)?

Comment: The 4th column starting from column D (i.e. the first column in `rw`) is column G.  So to reference column D in your original code you should have used `rw.Cells(n, 1)`, i.e. the first column of `rw` in the nth row of `rw`.

Comment: @YowE3K So replace rw.cells(n,4) with rw.Cells(n, 1) and replace everything after with rw.Cells(n, 2) rw.Cells(n, 3) etc....

Comment: The answer by @comintern is probably the best way to go, but there is still an issue with his loop that needs to be fixed.  (Hopefully he will do so soon.)   EDIT - Now fixed.

Comment: `For n = nlast To 9 Step -1`  worked for now but like @YowE3K said I need to clean up my loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are using the row and column indexes of `UsedRange` with the assumption that they match the indexes of the `Worksheet`.  This isn't necessarily the case.  As you pointed out to @YowE3K in the comments, you have some completely empty columns.

The solution is pretty easy - just use the `ws.Cells` instead of `rw.Cells`.  I'd also throw everything inside the loop into a `With` block to make it faster and more readable.  You can also short-circuit that long `If` statement by converting it into a `Select Case` ladder:

```
Sub RemoveEmptyRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        With ws
            Dim n As Long
            Dim nlast As Long
            nlast = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
            For n = nlast To 9 Step -1
                Select Case False
                    Case .Cells(n, 4).Value = vbNullString
                    Case .Cells(n, 5).Value = vbNullString
                    Case .Cells(n, 6).Value = vbNullString
                    Case .Cells(n, 7).Value = vbNullString
                    Case .Cells(n, 8).Value = vbNullString
                    Case .Cells(n, 9).Value = vbNullString
                    Case .Cells(n, 10).Value = vbNullString
                    Case .Cells(n, 11).Value = vbNullString
                    Case Else
                        .Rows(n).Delete
                End Select
            Next n
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Note that there are also more reliable ways to find the last row of the sheet.

Comment: @MTBthePRO - Yup. Fixed.

Comment: `For n = nlast To 9 Step -1`

Answer (score 1):

your Title is in C8, then don't delete until Row number 1 :

replace

```
For n = nlast To 1 Step -1
```

by

```
For n = nlast To 9 Step -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code a little amended.

```
Sub RemoveEmptyRows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long
    Dim nlast As Long
    Dim rw As Range

    For Each ws In Worksheets 'changed. In case there are Chart Sheets.
    'deleted ws.activate. AVOID THAT AS PLAGUE
        Set rw = ws.UsedRange.Rows
        With rw
            nlast = .Count
            For n = nlast To 2 Step -1 'Note the 2, to skip title row. As was pointed in comments.
                If (.Cells(n, 4).Value2 = "" And .Cells(n, 5).Value2 = "" And .Cells(n, 6).Value2 = "" And .Cells(n, 7).Value2 = "" And .Cells(n, 8).Value2 = "" And .Cells(n, 9).Value2 = "" And .Cells(n, 10).Value2 = "" And .Cells(n, 11).Value2 = "") Then
                    .Rows(n).Delete
                End If
            Next n
        End With 'rw
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (not tested) code:

```
Sub RemoveEmptyRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim nCols As Long

    For Each ws In Sheets
        With Intersect(.Range("D:K"), .UsedRange)
            nCols = .Columns.Count
            With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
                For iArea = .Areas.Count To 1 Step -1
                    If .Areas(iArea).Count = nCols Then .Areas(iArea).EntireRow.Delete
                Next
            End With
        End With
    Next ws  
End Sub
```